# How to Update Tex Live on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, texlive-2016, update

I just installed a newer version of Tex Live on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit
but when I type in the terminal: 
tex --version
the answer is:
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
Why if I just installed the 2016 version?

Thanks so much!

Comment: (1) welcome,  (2) How and what exactly did you just install? My guess is you manually installed upstream texlive, but forgot to manually adjust the PATH variable correctly

Comment: Hello! Thanks! I downloaded from 
http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
then I wrote in the terminal sudo ./install-tl from the directory where the installation script was located. 

Then I corrected the PATH in the ./bashsc script 
PATH=~/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/":$PATH"

Now when I type in the terminal tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016)

Comment: You have probably not added the path correctly.

Comment: sorry I didn't finish to edit the answer...
I need a Tex version higher then 4, plus when I compile the .tex file in the log I find: 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

Answer (score 3):

Set the `$PATH` variable to include the binaries of the new TeX installation. On my computer, the programs of TeXLive are in the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux`, so I added the lines

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
```

to `$HOME/.profile`. To modify the path also for non-interactive shells (like for remote login), you may have to take extra steps depending on your shell and its habits when to load which initialization files. For `bash`, my `$HOME/.bashrc` contains

```
# If running interactively, then:
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  ... all the commands and aliases only needed interactively
else
  source ~/.profile
fi
```

In fact, the installation script tells you in the end which directory you have to include in your command path (as well as the adjustments regarding `$MANPATH` and `$INFOPATH`).

Additionally I suggest to deinstall the texlive packages from Ubuntu, to avoid that the two TeX installations accidentally interfere. Search for all packages starting with `texlive-`.

Comment: No! Do not add it to bashrc, then if, say,  you are starting texmaker from a menu, then texmaker cannot find latex as it never execute a bash shell. Might be better to add it to `.profile` log out and in again.

Comment: I changed the path in profile and left bashrc as it was originally, but I still have the same problem...

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: If you change `.profile` you have to log out from your session and log in again for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @daleif Thanks, I didn't think of that since I use TeX from the command line only. But you are completely right, I will edit the post.

Comment: @Aleh Besides starting a new session: make sure the variable assignments in `.profile` are prefixed with `export`.

Comment: this is exactly what I added in the profile file:

export PATH=~/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/":$PATH"

Then I started a new session as well, now the log file of my .tex says:

 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.9.19) 19 SEP 2016 18:14

but the version is still the wrong one... I need a version higher than 4. Sorry, I am not so expert...

Comment: `echo $PATH` says
`/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: @Aleh did you actually install it into your home directory (as you indicate here with the `~/`) or is it in `/usr/local/... ` (which sounds more normal)

Comment: Sorry before I corrected the `.profile` with `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH`

Comment: @gernot I'm a cli jockey as well, but so many Linux users have been having issues so better leave a better version for others to find.

Comment: @Aleh you'll know that you got it right when `which latex` (in a terminal) gives the correct path to latex

Comment: @Aleh There is *definitely* no TeX version higher than 4. There will never, ever, be one because TeX versions are numbered by expanding the decimal places of pi. Your version is exactly the same version I have, installed today. So what's wrong with your current installation?

Comment: You can simply do `source ~/.profile`: no need to start a whole new section. Nor do you need to add the `export` before each line. But @Aleh: your `$PATH` is now OK.

Comment: @jon I think `export` is necessary in ~/.profile since it may also be processed by other shells, including plain `sh`. What do you mean by starting a new section? Or did you mean session? If you want to make sure that also the programs started from the GUI take notice of the changed PATH, then sourcing the profile in some subsidiary command shell doesn't help.

Comment: @gernot -- Oops, I meant 'session', not section. And that, of course, `source`-ing would (only) affect the current instance of the terminal session. ... I lost the context of the bigger question as I only start programs from a shell. Does that impact the need for `export` also? I've never used `export` in `.profile` and I've never had a problem. How would I trigger the failure to find, say, `pdflatex` (just curious)?

Comment: @jon Probably in Linux it doesn't really matter since sh has been replaced by bash, as far as I know, so it's maybe only relevant for other Unixes. But for classical sh and maybe other shells, variable settings are only handed over to sub-processes if they are exported.

Comment: Thanks all! Your comments were really useful. So, if I got it right, now my Tex Live version is up to date. Unfortunately Copernicus still doesn't accept the pdfs that it produces. But definitely the point was to add to the `.profile` file the `PATH`,`MANPATH`,`INFOPATH` lines, with `export` at the beginning of all of them. Thanks!